# Erro: IDLE deixa de funcionar após fechado

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho um laboratório com 35 máquinas rodando Windows 8.1 Pro. Após instalar o Python (Versão 2.7.9 64bits) em todas as máquinas, me deparo com os seguintes problemas:

- Algumas máquinas instalam normalmente, porém não é possível abrir o IDLE. Ao clicar no atalho, o IDLE simplesmente não abre. Não me é exibida nenhuma mensagem de erro.
- Outras máquinas funcionam corretamente, consigo abrir o IDLE, digitar código, executar. Só que ao fechar a ferramenta e tentar abrir novamente, volto ao problema mencionado anteriormente.
- Quando o IDLE deixa de funcionar (não consigo abrir mais), também deixa de funcionar via prompt de comando. Quando tento executar algum código via prompt de comando, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

  ```
  Traceback (most recente call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 400, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py", line 1
    Version" valueType="REG_SZ" value="1.0" operationHint="replace" owner="true" />
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

Alguma maneira de resolver isso? Existe algum problema de compatibilidade conhecido com o Windows 8.1?

Comment: Qual a versão do IDLE você está usando? aparece algum erro quando você usa em linha de comando? `python -m idlelib`

Comment: Estou usando a versão instalada juntamente com o python, versão 2.7.9. Ainda não tive a oportunidade de testar em linha de comando. Assim que testar, adiciono o resultado.

Comment: Testei em linha de comando e deixa de funcionar também. Não testei o comando que você mostrou @qmechanik mas consigo executar normalmente em outro computador via prompt de comando, já em um computador em que o IDLE deixou de funcionar, via prompt também não funciona.

Comment: Fiz a instalação utilizando o EXE baixado do site oficial. Não alterei nenhuma configuração. O código que tentei executar via prompt,  após o IDLE deixar de funcionar, foi um print normal.

Comment: Quanto a executar o comando Python no prompt, já me deparei com duas situações: as vezes o IDLE deixa de funcionar mas consigo executar via prompt e em outras vezes tudo para de funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Este o erro é de sintaxe do arquivo UserDict.py no diretório lib dentro da instalação do Python. Está claro que é um arquivo XML e não o código fonte original deste módulo em Python. Tente trocar o conteúdo deste arquivo pelo conteúdo original. Na própria documentação do Python é possível conferir rapidamente.

Link: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py

É fato que alguém ou alguma coisa trocou o conteúdo do arquivo. E provavelmente de muitos outros.

Recomendo observar os processos na máquina ou o que ocorre após a instalação, até a corrupção dos arquivos.